# Current buffer name as argument to org babel source block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

How do I pass the current file with its path to one of my source block in org-babel? For example:

```
#+name: cflow
#+header: var file=<what to put here?>
#+begin_src sh :exports none
  # output posix format
  # -i <symbol> include name start with <symbol> file
  # brief input
  cflow --format=posix -i _ --brief
#+end_src
```

I want the command to execute at the current directory of my buffer.

Answer (score 5):

This will do it:

```
var file=(buffer-file-name)
```

Comment: Ah, we can use Elisp in the place? Great. Thanks for the info.